How to assess brake fluid?
Sites suggest to flush brake fluid every two to three years or earlier if it appears dark or murky. There are also test strips which detect copper in the fluid, suggesting that it may be corroding the lines.
When you visually inspect fluid, the most obvious place to look is in the master cylinder. But I wonder, how does the fluid circulate up into the cylinder, or do you potentially have fluid which looks pretty and pristine at the top of the car, but sitting closer to the caliper, you have fluid which is accumulating rust and sediment? Should you rather quickly bleed the brakes to "take a sample" of fluid closer to the business end of the system?
Lastly, do these test strips have any value whatsoever?

That seems a good idea – to bleed the brakes occasionally to get rid of the crud and introduce fresh fluid. It's been a couple of decades, perhaps, since motor service engineers started saying the brake fluid needs changing, either because it's been there 3 years or "it failed a boiling point test". Yet my my Mk I UK model Ford Focus is 20 years old, has never had the fluid changed, and there is no sign of inefficiency or sponginess.

@WeatherVane - Whether or not you have noticed any signs of "inefficiency or sponginess", I can guarantee you it is not as good as it was when put in new. I'd highly suggest you consider changing it, because you're not doing your vehicle or yourself any favors. The brake fluid would probably work just fine as it is ... up until the point where you need to perform at its best. Then of course, it will fail, either through boiling or what have you. Then it's all over but the crying.

GM manuals, one from 20 years ago, brake fluid service in simple terms. When brakes are serviced; replacing brake pads/rotors/drums/brake shoes - brake fluid is flushed, replaced and bled to rid old fluid in a system with fresh new fluid. Since brake master cylinders are vented to allow fluid in the reservoir to drop as disc brake pads wear down, fluid absorbs moisture, lowering its boiling point.  This applies to DOT3, 4, 5 brake fluid.  $10 per quart is cheap insurance to have new fluid after every brake service. New fluid is light honey colored. Dark fluid oxidizes, absorbing moisture.

@FDryer in this case I have used car with incomplete service history. I plan to flush the system for the same reasons you mentioned. When I took a peek at the master cylinder, the fluid looked great so I was curious hence the question.
